# HTTP headers are not being sent in CORS GET from AngularJS application

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, cors, angularjs-http

My problem is that HTTP headers are not being sent from my AngularJS HTTP GET requests. However, for a HTTP POST, I do see the headers being set. These HTTP requests are over CORS.

Although there are a lot of SO posts on this problem, I have tried them and none of them worked. One of the solutions suggests that HTTP headers are not sent if the data field is empty, and I've tried the suggestion to add an empty data value (which doesn't really sense for a HTTP GET request, by the way), but still, the HTTP headers do not make it.

On a side note, I might defend that this post/question may merit itself as "not a duplicate" (from the other SO posts) as it deals with HTTP GET (as opposed to HTTP POST) and CORS (as opposed to not-CORS).

Here is my technology stack.

- NodeJS v4.2.2
- Express v4.13.3
- AngularJS v1.4.0

To enable CORS, I followed the example here http://enable-cors.org/server_expressjs.html. My NodeJS server application looks like the following.

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken'); 

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

var router = express.Router();
var app = express();

app.set('secret', 'mySecret');
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use('/api', router);


router.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, x-access-token');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, PUT, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE');
  next();
});

router.post('/authenticate', function(req, res) {
  var username = req.body.username;
  var pw = req.body.password;
  if(username !== 'root') {
    res.json({
      success: false,
      message: 'User not found'
    });
  } else if(pw !== 'root') {
    res.json({
      success: false,
      message: 'Password wrong'
    });
  } else {
    var user = {
      username: username,
      pw: pw
    };
    var token = jwt.sign(user, app.get('secret'), {
      expiresIn: 60 * 60 * 24 * 365
    });
    res.json({
      success: true,
      message: 'Enjoy your token!',
      token: token
    });
  }
});

router.use(function(req, res, next) {
  /* according to comments, have to ignore OPTIONS request from protection */
  if('OPTIONS' === req.method) { next(); return; } //original post modified here to show, after adding this line, the OPTIONS is accessible, then the GET does actually send the required HTTP header
  if('/api/authenticate' === req.originalUrl) {
    next();
    return;
  }

  var token = req.body.token || req.params['token'] || req.headers['x-access-token'];
  if(token) {
    jwt.verify(token, app.get('secret'), function(err, decoded) {
      if(err) {
        return res.json({
          success: false,
          message: 'Failed to authenticate token'
        });
      } else {
        req.decoded = decoded;
        next();
      }
    })
  } else {
    return res.status(403).send({
      success: false,
      message: 'No token provided'
    });
  }
});

router.get('/users', function(req, res) {
  res.json([
    { fname: 'john', lname: 'doe' },
    { fname: 'jane', lname: 'smith' }
  ]);
})

var server = app.listen(port, function() {
  var host = server.address().address;
  var port = server.address().port;
  console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

My AngularJS service looks like the following.

```
myServices.factory('HomeService', ['$resource', '$http', '$location', '$cookies', 'conf', function($resource, $http, $location, $cookies, conf) {
  var svc = {};

  svc.getRestUrl = function() {
    return 'http://localhost:8080';
  };

  svc.sendData = function(url, data, method) {
    var restUrl = svc.getRestUrl() + url;
    var options = {
      method: method,
      url: restUrl,
      withCredentials: false
    };

    var token = $cookies.get('token');
    if(_.isEmpty(token)) {
      options.headers = {
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
      };
    } else {
      options.headers = {
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
        'x-access-token': token
      };
    }

    if(data) {
      options.data = data;
    } else {
      options.data = '';
    }

    return $http(options);
  }

  svc.getData = function(url) {
    return svc.sendData(url, null, 'GET');
  };

  svc.postData = function(url, data) {
    return svc.sendData(url, data, 'POST');
  };

  svc.authenticate = function(username, password) {
    var data = JSON.stringify({
      username: username,
      password: password
    });
    return svc.postData('/api/authenticate', data);
  };

  svc.getUsers = function() {
    return svc.getData('/api/users');
  };

  return svc;
}]);
```

Note

- for the service's `authenticate` method, this is a HTTP POST
- for the service's `getUsers`, this a HTTP GET
- when there is no data to send (HTTP GET), the data is set to empty `data: ''`

Using Fiddler, for `authenticate` I see the following HTTP request.

```
POST http://localhost:8080/api/authenticate HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 37
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Origin: http://localhost
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Referer: http://localhost/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8

{"username":"root","password":"root"}
```

For `getUsers`, I see the following HTTP request.

```
OPTIONS http://localhost:8080/api/users HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Origin: http://localhost
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: accept, x-access-token, x-requested-with
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

Am I missing something here with regards to HTTP GET over CORS that the HTTP headers are not being sent?

Comment: Which one happens first in your code ? GET request or POST request ? If you notice, in case of GET, an OPTIONS request is getting fired which is a preflighted request that happens when you send a custom header in the request.

Comment: The POST should happen first to `authenticate` to get the JSON Web Token (JWT), followed by the GET to `getUsers` (using JWT).

Comment: The response for OPTIONS seems good, listing the allowed origin, headers and methods. It is what I expected.

Comment: It seems to be with my middleware and OPTIONS. When the OPTIONS request is made, I get a 403 (not seen in Fiddler but shown in Chrome console). It seems I should exclude OPTIONS request as a protected resource. Any idea on how to do that?

Comment: As you're handling only post and get requests in your nodejs server, OPTIONS request is going to default handler where you're checking for token and if token is not available, you're committing `403` response with `res.status(403).send({})`. I think you should change your code to handle OPTIONS request here

Comment: AH, thanks that worked. I'll edit my POST.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to your HTTP request, an OPTIONS request is fired to your CORS API icase of your `getUsers` method.

When it comes to CORS, there are 2 kinds of requests

1. Simple Requests
2. Preflighted Requests

**Simple requests**

A simple cross-site request is one that meets all the following conditions:

The only allowed methods are:

- GET
- HEAD
- POST

Apart from the headers set automatically by the user agent, the only headers which are allowed to be manually set are:

- Accept
- Accept-Language
- Content-Language
- Content-Type

The only allowed values for the Content-Type header are:

- application/x-www-form-urlencoded
- multipart/form-data
- text/plain

**Preflighted requests**

In case you make any request which violates the conditions of a simple request, then a "preflighted" OPTIONS request is sent in order to determine whether the actual request is safe to send.In particular, a request is preflighted if:

- It uses methods other than GET, HEAD or POST.  Also, if POST is used
  to send request data with a Content-Type other than
  application/x-www-form-urlencoded, multipart/form-data, or
  text/plain, e.g. if the POST request sends an XML payload to the
  server using application/xml or text/xml, then the request is
  preflighted.
- It sets custom headers in the request (e.g. the request uses a header
  such as X-PINGOTHER)

For more details about Preflighted Requests, you can refer to this MDN [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests).

I believe this is what is happening in your case. Even though you're making a simple GET request, you're adding 2 custom headers `X-Requested-With` & `x-access-token` which makes it necessary to validate the safety of your API, so a preflighted OPTIONS request is sent by the browser. The browser will continue with your GET request only if it receives valid response.

In your NodeJS server code, you're handling only POST requests to `/authenticate` and GET requests to `/users`, so in case of an OPTIONS request, it's going to the default handler where you're checking for token and if it's not available, you respond with a `403`. So I suggest you change your code to handle `OPTIONS` request as well.